# Lie algebra with extended base field

Tags: lie-algebras, extension-field, tensor-products

Let $g$ be a Lie algebra over $k$ with $k\subset k'$. The task is to define a Lie bracket for $g'=k'\bigotimes g$.

I have tried $[x\bigotimes a, y\bigotimes b]:=(x-y)\bigotimes [a,b]$; while this satisfies the first condition $[x,x]=0$, it does not satisfy the Jacobi identity. I  think I'm missing something important.

Comment: $(x-y)\otimes[a,b]$ is trilinear in $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$, but you need something quadrilinear in the four variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define $$[x\otimes a,y\otimes b]=xy\otimes[a,b].$$

Comment: But then $[x\bigotimes a, x\bigotimes a]=x^2\bigotimes [a,a]=x^2$ which is not necessarily zero?

Comment: Why not? $[a,a]=0$, since $g$ is a Lie algebra.

Comment: @SidCaroline So what? $x^2\otimes[a,a]=x^2\otimes0=0$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the last equality.

Comment: @SidCaroline In a Lie algebra, $[a,a]=0$ for all $a$.

Comment: @SidCaroline You always have $a\otimes 0=0$, because$$a\times0=a\otimes(0+0)=a\otimes0+a\otimes0.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, that's exactly where I got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean $g'=k'\otimes_k g$?

If so, then
$$[x\otimes a,y\otimes b]=xy\otimes[a,b]$$
works.